# Errors when compiling, cannot see clear error in code

Tags: c++, windows

I'm modifying the STablUpd code example on MSDN (For editing string tables in resources) however, I'm running into a few errors.

The code that the errors are situated in is

```
HSTRBLOCK strBlock = GetStringBlockW( L"file.exe", 7, MAKELANGID(LANG_ENGLISH, SUBLANG_ENGLISH_UK) );
UINT str1Len;
GetStringLength( strBlock, str1Len );
LPWSTR pszString1;
GetStringW(strBlock, 6, pszString1 );
MessageBox(NULL, (LPCSTR) pszString1, NULL, NULL);
```

and the errors I receive are as follows

```
Error   4   error C2065: 'pszString1' : undeclared identifier   tabledlg.c  190 1   STablUpd
Error   5   error C2065: 'pszString1' : undeclared identifier   tabledlg.c  191 1   STablUpd
Error   8   error C2065: 'pszString1' : undeclared identifier   tabledlg.c  192 1   STablUpd
Error   3   error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'pszString1'  tabledlg.c  190 1   STablUpd
Error   2   error C2275: 'LPWSTR' : illegal use of this type as an expression   tabledlg.c  190 1   STablUpd
```

Any anybody point out if there are any errors in this please, I've checked but the code seems fine to me.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that `LPWSTR` is not defined. Either you're missing an `include`, or you're including the file but the type is excluded by some pre-processor directives.

See [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/76252/What-are-TCHAR-WCHAR-LPSTR-LPWSTR-LPCTSTR-etc) for more info.

Comment: I have the following Preprocessor definitions, `WIN32
NDEBUG
_WINDOWS _VC80_UPGRADE=0x0600` and I cannot find anythign about preprocessor directives. What do I need to include for LPWSTR to work correctly?